Python Protocol using keyword-only arguments requires implementation to have different signature
I'm on python 3.10. I'm using PyCharm's default type checker and MyPy.
Here is the protocol I defined:
class OnSubscribeFunc(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, instrument: str, *, x: int) -> AsyncGenerator:
        ...

When create a method that implements it like this:
class A:
    async def subscribe(self, instrument: str, *, x: int):
        yield ...
a: OnSubscribeFunc = A().subscribe  # this apparently is where it gets it wrong

I get this warning: Expected type 'OnSubscribeFunc', got '(instrument: str, Any, x: int) -> AsyncGenerator' instead
If I remove the * from my implementation however, the warning disappears. I would expect it to be the other way around because not having the * allows the implementation to have non-keyword-only arguments which might not be what I'm aiming for with my protocol.
So for comparison - this implementation gives no warning:
class A:
    async def subscribe(self, instrument: str, x: int):
        yield ...

This does not make any sense to me, why does it behave like this and is this expected or is it a bug in my type checker?

Please edit the question to provide a [mre] and the name of the type checker you are using (probably Mypy).

@InSync The example is reproducable. Just assign the subscribe method to a variable typed as a: OnSubscribeFunc = instance.subscribe. Also why did you remove the "python-3.x" tag? This only applies to python 3

Nowadays we mean "Python 3" whenever we say "Python", so the tag is redundant. See this Meta post. Also, the original example is not reproducible without the name of the type checker.

@TimWoocker python-3.10 would only be the correct tag if this behavior was specific to that minor version of Python 3, not just because you happen to be using Python 3.10.

@chepner Yes, I don't know why someone edited the question to unclude that tag: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/79111951/revisions

This is a known bug of PyCharm. Mypy and Pyright both accept your code as it is.
Put a # type: ignore or # noqa there and move on.
